# Is there an XSLT buddy available somewhere?

Tags: xml, xslt

I think a lot of people know about tools like RegexBuddy. Is there something similar for XSLT?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*XSLT IDEs* (Interactive Development Environments):

- **[XSelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xselerator)** (the one I've been using for 6-7 years). Free, has a Debugger for MSXML, has intellisense for both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. In addition has some dynamic intellisense. The debugger has breakpoints, data breakpoints,visualizes temporary trees, variables, test conditions, current output, ..., etc.
- **[VS2008](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/default.mspx)** -- a good XML Editor + XSLT Debugger. Good static intellisence. Match patterns are statically checked. Breakpoints, data breakpoints, visualization of variables and the current output.
- **[oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)**
- **[XML-SPY](http://www.altova.com/products/xmlspy/xml_editor.html) (Altova)**
- **[Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/)**

*XPath tools*:

- **The [XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV-Zip-2008.zip)** -- A [**popular tool for learning XPath**](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html) by playing with XPath expressions. Free and open source. Allows any XPath expression to be evaluated against a given XML document and displayes the results hi-lighted in the xml document (if they are node(s)) or in a separate box (if the results are atomic values). Allows xsl:variable-s to be defined and then used in XPath expressions. Allows xsl:key-s to be defined and then referenced by key() functions within XPath expressions.

**EDIT**: The XPath Visualizer now has a **[new, safer home](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**, due to the kindness of Lars Huttar.

Comment: @Dimitre - thanks for posting the link to Xselerator! I've been using it for years (7?). When Marrow stopped selling it, I didn't know where  it went. Now I know :)

Comment: Found myself struggling with the Visual Studio xslt debugger a lot, Xselerator's debugger seems a lot better (although suffers from programmer UI syndrome somewhat)

Comment: except xselector, I have used All other XSL tools :)) thanks for suggesting :) my UV :)

Comment: Yes, the XSelerator is a classical example of good usability engineering.

Comment: @Dimitre: unfortunately the XSelerator-link seems to be broken.

Comment: @concilliator: Yes, I have talked to the author of the XSelerator. He is looking for a suitable site to place the XSelerator. Until then you can ask someone having it for the msi file or try internetarchive.org for the last existing version of http://sf.net/projects/xselerator

Answer (score 4):

This is the closest I know that is free: [XML Copy Editor](http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/)

Altova XML Spy is excellent but expensive.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to experiment with an XSLT expression, there's [a sandbox in Orbeon Forms](http://ogres.sandre.eaufrance.fr/orbeon/sandbox-transformations/xslt/). Obviously, there are a bunch more features in RegexBuddy that this has no equivalent to, but it's a nice interactive way to play with some strange XSLT expression that you're trying to debug.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @Abel.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Architag XRay](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/XRay-XML-Editor.shtml) in the past (I have [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) now).
XRay is free and lightweight.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning XRay. I am using it almost every day since I read this your answer.

Answer (score 0):

And your guerilla option, the bugged and seemingly unsupported free family favourite: [XML cooktop](http://www.xmlcooktop.com/)