# use xsl to convert an xml file to name-value pair

Tags: xslt

Consider my knowledge in XSL files to be 3 ou of 10
With that said, I've been faced with a task of converting an xml file to name/value pair using xsl. I couldn't find any examples out there on how it can be done. Also, what do you recommend for a free tool to test the xsl?

Answer (score 1):

> I've been faced with a task of
>   converting an xml file to name/value
>   pair using xsl.

**Although this is too-generic to be a well-defined problem, here is one possible answer**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
      "concat(name(), ' = ', .,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (product of my fantasy):

```
<t>
 <first-name>John</first-name>
 <last-name>Smith</last-name>
 <age>33</age>
</t>
```

**the (what I guess is) wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
first-name = John
last-name = Smith
age = 33
```

> Also, what do you recommend for a free
>   tool to test the xsl?

**See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407910/is-there-an-xslt-buddy-available-somewhere/408096#408096)**.