# Is there a Ctags like tool for browsing/navigating XSLT code in Vim?

Tags: xslt, vim, plugins, ctags

Need a way to navigate/browse XSLT files easily with Vim. 
Similar to the way ctags can be used with C/C++ source code.
A good solution would allow installing scripts etc only for self or running them directly from inside Vim. Hate having to step out of vim just to search for a function definition or "text" search.

Searched for a few hours and came up with some good leads like 'ack'.
Apparently this can be integrated with vim using ack.vim. Yet to test this out properly.

Essentially I should be able to go through a maze of .xsl files which include other .xsl files and use functions, templates. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe to write your own TAGs generator. The fileformat is really simple. Then its just an AST tree....

Comment: @Dimitre: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags, http://ctags.sourceforge.net/, and `:help ctags` in Vim

Comment: @ib: If you want to increase the chances of people answering a question, dont suppose they know anything labeled with an acronym or that they will spend time looking into Wikipedia. This question, as is, has almost nothing to do with XSLT and is not a complete and meaningful question. If you are just asking about what XSLT IDEs (Interactive Development Environments) exist, just say so in your question. Then you can find answers that already exist, such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407910/is-there-an-xslt-buddy-available-somewhere/408096#408096

Comment: @Izap: Yes http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html talks about that. But my question is if this has already been done. Don't want to redo time-consuming work if it's already out there (somewhere).

Comment: @Izap: An example TAGs file or time to write it out would have helped evaluate your answer earlier. 'AST' tree et. al. made me think it might be a complex task. Thanks anyway.

Found good info on customizing ctags for new languages.
Need to add to ~/.ctags file the following a) new language definition, b) filetype, c) one or more regular-expression patterns for identifiying new language constructs.
[Creating and Using Ctags files with Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags)

Comment: @Izap Want to select your answer as it's the closest to a working solution. Unable to do that or upvote this question.

Comment: Checked the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) - it says to use check box to left of answer to "accept answer". No such check-box available.

Comment: Pending acceptance of @Izap's answer I've posted complete solution as a blog post [Browsing XSLT with Ctags and Vim](http://techtalkies.blogspot.com/2011/07/browsing-xslt-with-vim-by-adding-custom.html)

Comment: Decided to post the solution that worked for me inside stackoverflow rather than "outsourcing" it from my blog. Might help someone here.  
I'll update the blog [Browsing XSLT with Ctags and Vim](http://techtalkies.blogspot.com/2011/07/browsing-xslt-with-vim-by-adding-custom.html) and this post in case I find a better way to solve the problem or make it more generic.   
By the way, the blog also contains extra links on getting javascript, bash, perl support with ctags.

Comment: @Izap +1 for your TAGs file answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the kipelovets' and GuruM's answers to be useful and worked out this solution that combines their advice.:

.ctags file:

```
--langdef=xslt
--langmap=xslt:.xsl
--regex-xslt=/<xsl:template[^>]+name=\"([-a-zA-Z0-9_:]+)\"( +mode="([^"]+)")?/\1 \2/n,namedtemplate/i
--regex-xslt=/<xsl:template[^>]+match=\"([^"]+)\"( +mode="([^"]+)")?/\1     \2/m,matchedtemplate/i
--regex-xslt=/<xsl:apply-templates +select="([^"]{2,})"( +mode="([^"]+)")?/\1 \2/a,applytemplate/i
--regex-xslt=/<xsl:call-template +select="([^"]+)"( +mode="([^"]+)")?/\1 \2/c,calltemplate/i
--regex-xslt=/<xsl:variable[^>]+name=\"([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\"/\1/v,variable/i
--regex-xslt=/<xsl:function[^>]+name=\"([-a-zA-Z0-9_:]+)\"/\1/f,function/i
--regex-xslt=/<xsl:param[^>]+name=\"([-a-zA-Z0-9_:]+)\"/\1/p,parameter/i
```

vim tagbar settings (which some people may find useful):

```
let g:tagbar_type_xslt = {
      \ 'ctagstype' : 'xslt',
      \ 'kinds'     : [
      \ 'n:templates (named)',
      \ 'm:templates (matched)',
      \ 'a:applied templates',
      \ 'c:called templates',
      \ 'f:functions',
      \ 'p:parameters',
      \ 'v:variables'
      \ ]
      \ }
```

It's better, but some issues I am still having include:

- grouping templates by their modes
- white space such as new lines in between attributes for a template/variable etc...
- scoping variables and parameters and apply templates and call templates

  - So if you have multiple variables with the same name but in different templates,
    the scope of which template they are in is not be captured.
- commented templates, functions, variables and parameters

A better approach to try in future:

- The regex's for parsing the information from the xslt get complex to do this properly
- The best solution may be to write a custom xslt tag generator using xslt itself.

  - This is what [jsctags](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs) does for javascript
  - The format of the tag file looks straightforward... so I will try this next.

    - See [Tag File Format](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html#TAG%20FILE%20FORMAT)

Comment: Wow!! I stopped using my own solution as it did not search for named, matched, apply-templates, call-templates. Ran short of time trying to get my solution to work. But your solution does just that!! I guess *this* is why open source works... Each person contributing just that little bit more. Hopefully someone will come along and build on top of what you've done. Or are you going to try it it out yourself?

Comment: Thanks - I am going to try writing the xsltctags myself.  I've written enough XSLT over the years, where I would love to have something better.  The above helped be traverse some poorly written XSLT recently... but it could be better.  I'll post an update here when I have a prototype in github.

Comment: Best of Luck on your implementation.

Comment: Any luck with your implementation? Might help someone if you post link to your prototype on github.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your question and answer @GuruM

though your version of ~/.ctags didn't work for me, i used following:

```
--langdef=xslt
--langmap=xslt:.xsl
--regex-xslt=/<xsl:template[^>]+name=\"([-a-zA-Z0-9_:]+)\"/\1/f,function/i
```

it works perfectly with AutoTag plugin and requires only one following line for TagList plugin:

```
let s:tlist_def_xslt_settings = 'xslt;f:function'
```

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the info. +1 for your suggestion.  
Note that you're using f,function for xsl:template. Shouldn't it be t,template ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Izap. Sorry apparently I'm not allowed to upvote my own question.
Couldn't select your answer even though it's closest to what I wanted (example code would've helped).
Creating a tags file can be done very easily:
1) Test out the regular-expressions for your custom language: `egrep 'pattern' *`
2) Copy-paste custom language with the above regular-expressions into ~/.ctags.

```
--langdef=EXSLT
--langmap=EXSLT:.xsl
--regex-EXSLT=/<xsl:variable[ \t]+name=\"([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\"/\1/v,variable/i
--regex-EXSLT=/<func:function[ \t]+name=\"([-a-zA-Z0-9_:]+)\"/\1/f,function/i
--regex-EXSLT=/<xsl:template[ \t]+match=\"([/-a-zA-Z0-9_:]+)\"/\1/t,template/i
```

Note: The ( and ) are used to create a tag-entry in tags file where \1 is the matching keyword. Here I'm adding xslt with exslt support above.
You can extend the language mapping by appending regular-expression patterns below.
3) Run `cd srcdir && ctags -R *`
4) Check the tags file to see if ctags has found the patterns
5) Open vim and test out the tags file using Ctrl-] to jump from function usage to definition etc.
Note: ["Extending"](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html) ctags requires C coding and is not discussed here.